# Syntax error in SQL , Incorrect syntax near ''

Tags: sql

What is wrong in this?

[image]

The error comes from this section;

```
        AND ('''+@searchText+''' = '''' OR (ISNULL(CAST(t1.id as varchar(10)),'''') + '' '' +
                                    ISNULL(CAST(FORMAT(t1.reading_date,@dateformat) as varchar(12)),'''')+'' '' +
                                    ISNULL(t2.description,'''') + '' '' +
                                    ISNULL(t3.equipment_no,'''') + '' '' +
                                    ISNULL(t4.description,'''') + '' '' + 
                                    ISNULL(CAST(t1.actual_usage as nvarchar(16)),'''') + '' '' +
                                    ISNULL(t5.uom_code,'''') + '' '' +
                                    ISNULL(CAST(t1.actual_cost as nvarchar(16)),'''') + '' '' +
                                    ISNULL(t6.currency_code,'''') + '' '' +
                                    ISNULL(t1.comment,'''') + '' '' +
                                    ISNULL(CAST(FORMAT(t1.actual_date,@dateformat) as varchar(12)),'''')) LIKE ''%'' '''+@searchText+''' ''%'')
```

The error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 59
Incorrect syntax near ''.
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason for dynamic SQL here, and you're making life very difficult on yourself by using it, as now you are in quoting hell. `QUOTENAME` can help some here, but it's better to avoid it altogether. Even if it's absolutely necessary here for the rest of the query (you don't show), this part can still simply use parameter values throughout (passed to `sp_executesql`) and using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to avoid parameter sniffing. I would advise you to read this and rethink your approach: https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html Table-valued functions are another option.

Comment: is `searchText` the field you want to search?

Comment: Another issue which is persistent throughout your query, even if it happens to work here: [using `VARCHAR` without a length is a bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT(string1, string2, ...., string_n) instead of doing it manually using + operator. Also, use COALESCE to return column value or empty string.  This will simplify the query.

Sample for using CONCAT()

```html
DECLARE @searchText AS VARCHAR(50) = 'SearchMe'
DECLARE @sqlQuery2 AS VARCHAR(5000)

DECLARE @Column1 AS VARCHAR(50) = 'TestValue1'

SET @sqlQuery2 = ' FROM Table 
                    WHERE Column1 = ''' + @Column1 + '''
                    AND ('''+@searchText+''' = '''' OR (CONCAT(
                                          ISNULL(CAST(t1.id as varchar(10)), '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(CAST(FORMAT(t1.reading_date,@dateformat) as varchar(12)), '''')
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(t2.description, '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(t3.equipment_no, '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(t4.description, '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(CAST(t1.actual_usage as nvarchar(16)), '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(t5.uom_code, '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(CAST(t1.actual_cost as nvarchar(16)), '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(t6.currency_code, '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(t1.comment, '''') 
                                        , '' '' 
                                        , ISNULL(CAST(FORMAT(t1.actual_date,@dateformat) as varchar(12)), ''''))
                                    )) LIKE ''% ' + @searchText + ' %''
    )
    ORDER BY someColumn '

select @sqlQuery2
```

Also noted that LIKE statement string in your code will return syntax error.

Replace the string

```
LIKE ''%'' ''' + @searchText + ''' ''%''
```

by this

```
LIKE ''% ' + @searchText + ' %''
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Could you show an example on how to do it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).